# Rails Routes Named Helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am coming across an odd problem, and am not sure how to correct.  I initially created a resource in my application with the full REST actions.  Once I started cleaning up the code, I realized I didn't need all of the actions, and changed the routes code to reflect that.  After doing that, it changed some of the Named Helpers around so that the "index" path is pointing to the create action and the helper path that was pointing to show now points to update.  I have made sure that the index_path is not being used in any of the code.  Is there a way to cleanly remove the actions that are no longer needed?

Original Code:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :license
  end
```

New Code:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :license, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end
```

Original Routes List for license:

```
user_license_index GET    /users/:user_id/license(.:format)                    license#index
                   POST   /users/:user_id/license(.:format)                    license#create
  new_user_license GET    /users/:user_id/license/new(.:format)                license#new
 edit_user_license GET    /users/:user_id/license/:id/edit(.:format)           license#edit
      user_license GET    /users/:user_id/license/:id(.:format)                license#show
                   PATCH  /users/:user_id/license/:id(.:format)                license#update
                   PUT    /users/:user_id/license/:id(.:format)                license#update
                   DELETE /users/:user_id/license/:id(.:format)                license#destroy
```

New Routes after removing index and show:

```
user_license_index POST   /users/:user_id/license(.:format)                    license#create
  new_user_license GET    /users/:user_id/license/new(.:format)                license#new
 edit_user_license GET    /users/:user_id/license/:id/edit(.:format)           license#edit
      user_license PATCH  /users/:user_id/license/:id(.:format)                license#update
                   PUT    /users/:user_id/license/:id(.:format)                license#update
                   DELETE /users/:user_id/license/:id(.:format)                license#destroy
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Another way to do it is to put `resources :license, except: [:index, :show]`. That will get you the same functionality as your "New Code" but it will be slightly cleaner.

Comment: Sorry, what I was asking was how can I remove the unwanted routes without having the helper paths shift to another action.  (I don't want the user_license_index helper to point to the create action)

Comment: So where do you want user_license_index to point to? As in, do you still want the #create action?

Comment: I don't want it to point to point to anything.  I want to remove it all together when I remove the index action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I understand what your question is. Here's the issue: `user_license_index` doesn't just point to the index action; it ALSO points to the create action. The difference is whether you use a GET or POST request (GET by default). However, the routes page only lists the helper once. So when you remove the index action, it removes the index route from the list so now `user_license_index` only points to the create action.

The same idea goes for `user_license`. It points to the show, update, and destroy actions. The difference is if you use a GET, PATCH/PUT, or DELETE request.

BTW, I think the reason why there is an `_index` suffix is that the word "license" is a singular-only word (just like "sheep" or "fish").